# How to Pass a JSON Values to Nunit Testcase Data

Tags: c#, nunit

I am reading a JSON file and stores the values as a object
Car : `Name`, `Cost`, `Yearmodel`

Now I need to pass these 3 JSON object values to this `Testcasedata`.
Likewise I need to pass multiple values while reading the JSON file data.
Any idea explaining on how to do this?

````
public string JSONParser()
        {


            StreamReader r = new StreamReader("ESAggregationQuery.json");
            string jsonString = r.ReadToEnd();
             m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AggModel>(jsonString);

            carName = m.carName;
            costPrice = m.costPrice;
            modelYear = m.modelYear;

            return "1";
        }

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ESAggregativeTestData
        {
            get
            {               
                    yield return new TestCaseData[] { m.carName, m.costPrice, m.modelYear };
                }

        }
```
````

Comment: There's not enough detail here to give you an answer, and quite honestly, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hi David.

I am reading a JSON file and has 3 fields.

Car = Swift
Cost = 270k
Modelyear  =2004.

I have Nunit testcase source method to which above 3 values are passed as arguments.

I will run some queries and validate using Assert method.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], don't just describe your code.

Comment: HI David, 

I am added that full code in the question itself.

As mentioned, object values are given as Test input. how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You don't "pass" data to your TestCaseData item. The data has to originate there. Try making the following changes...

1. Call your `JSONParser` from the getter of `ESAggregativeTestData` or add the code in there.
2. Change your `yield` statement to return a new `TestCaseData`, not an array. That's not an NUnit thing... it's just how `IEnumerable` works. If your JSON file, now or in the future, contains multiple test items, you will need to put all this in a loop.
3. You have not shown us your test code, which uses the data source. To work with the source you have given, it should take three arguments of the appropriate type.

Suggestion... next time provide more complete source code that shows what you are trying to do.